# Logos critique: Dayton Web Developers meeting

Tags: logo, critique

I created several logos for the Dayton Web Developers meeting. This logo will represent the web developers group in Dayton, OH.

The palette is based on a very popular Sublime Text theme called Cobalt2. Sublime Text is one of the most if not the most popular IDE in the web development community.

We like to abbreviate the Dayton Web Developers group as DWD.

EDIT-- Adding more info:

My concerns/comments with the designs are:

**Design #1**

- Maybe the circle badge feels too overused.
- I really like to highlight the symbol. The style of this symbol is the one I like the most.
- Not so sure about the blue text over the gold. I tried black text but it doesn't feel it fits.

**Design #2**

- I want to highlight the symbol but I feel without the gold outline it lacks punch.
- Not entirely sure about the gold circle on the outside.

**Design #3**

- Maybe this one works well for this style out of 3, 4 and 5, but the square ends feel too simple.
- I like the strength of the symbol, but I feel the rectangle in which the name is makes the logo lack presence.
- I like the typeface used.

**Design #4**

- Different typeface, more playful trying to contrast the straight lines of the rectangle.

**Design #5**

- Trying to break that stiffness of the rectangle with triangle ends, but I feel that there are too many triangles going on now.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: So are we voting on our favorite? Why don't you ask the web dev group to do that?

Comment: Can you provide *specific* areas you are concerned about? and expand upon why? It may help to review the [critique guidelines](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work) we have. As this stands, any answers would be purely opinion-based (I like that one) and not really a great question for StackExchange sites.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the recommendation, I added more information/comments about the logos. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Yeah, you can vote for your favorite but if you could provide your opinion on anything, that'd be very helpful. I've been working with the organizers, the idea is to do a reveal of the new logo. Let me know what you think. Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are nice. My favorite would have to be the upper right. The circle + omission of the outline make it the least 'pen nib' of the bunch which is really my only critique of the lot--a lot of them look like pen nibs. Now, maybe that's a GOOD thing perhaps (writing code is writing...).

Comment: @DA01 pen nib, you're right, didn't see it that way :). I agree, writing code is writing. Are you able to discern what the symbol means? Thanks for your input.

Comment: @ricardozea I see it as a monogram, correct?

Comment: @DA01, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between your 3rd and 4th logo is the typeface. 4th looks better, that is because the thickness of the font is almost the same as the thickness of the golden outline. 
Use that typeface in 5th logo, it might look even better. 
Try this on the all the logos and see which one looks the best to you. Always look at this detail. Rest all looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Client is liking #3, they are debating right now. Thanks for your input, greatly appreciate it.